# HttpRequest is not importing its methods

Tags: java, android

```
 protected Integer doInBackground(String... params)
   {

    String url="http://ff4627de.ngrok.io/"+"login.php";
    String status="";
    int id=0;

    try {
        HttpRequest httpRequest=new HttpRequest(url);
        HashMap<String ,String> value=new HashMap<>();
        value.put("email",params[0]);
        value.put("password",params[1]);
         JSONObject jsonObject=httpRequest.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST)
         .withData(value).sendAndReadJSON();
```

There is an error on new `HttpRequest(url)` and `.prepare()` method and `.Method`. It is showing that it cant resolve them.

Comment: Did you create your own `HttpRequest` class?

Comment: Well, are the methods private?

Comment: Yes i created HttpRequest class seperate

Comment: Can you include the HttpRequest class (if you wrote it) and the import statements?